# How can I flip .nii images using batch processing with python-nibabel?

Tags: python, list, image, loops, nibabel

I have 180 .nii fMRI images for each patient and I need to flip them from right to left. I've tried using 'for' statement to batch processing these images. But it seems like The following code only **produce one result**.
Here is the following code:

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import os

NII_DIR='/Users/lena/testtest'
def get_filelist(dir, Filelist):
    if os.path.isdir(dir):
        for s in os.listdir(dir):
            newDir = os.path.join(dir, s)
            Filelist.append(newDir)
    return Filelist

list = get_filelist(NII_DIR, [])
print(len(list))
type(list)

for i in list:
    def read_nii_file1(nii_path):
        nii_img=nib.load(nii_path)
        return nii_img
    nii_img=read_nii_file1(os.path.join(i))

    from nilearn.image import new_img_like
    print(nii_img.affine.shape)
    print(nii_img.affine)

    def flip_image(image, axis):
        try:
            new_data = np.copy(image.get_fdata())
            for axis_index in axis:
                new_data = np.flip(new_data, axis=axis_index)
        except TypeError:
            new_data = np.flip(image.get_fdata(), axis=axis)
        return new_img_like(image, data=new_data)

    new_image = flip_image(nii_img, axis=[0])

    affine = new_image.affine.copy()
    hdr = new_image.header.copy()

    new_data = new_image.get_fdata()
    new_nii = nib.Nifti1Image(new_data, affine, hdr)

#the following is the part I have no idea how to write
    New_NII_DIR = ('/Users/lena/test_new/001.nii')
    nib.save(new_nii, New_NII_DIR)
```

[here is the example of my data, including 180 phases][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDh34.png

Answer (score 1):

your New_NII_DIR should be different in each loop.